# ExpectedCondition method attributeContains for C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, wait

I was trying to use "attributeContains" method but I don't have it avaible when using C#. https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#attributeContains-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Any workaround?

Comment: Please put a sample of code in your question that helps us recreate the problem, or at least identify it. Posting a URL to a github repository is frowned on. Just show us the code that matters, right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always create your *custom Expected Condition*:

```
public void AttributeContains(By locator, String attribute, String value, int secondsToWait = 30)
{
   new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, secondsToWait))
      .Until(d => d.FindElement(locator).GetAttribute(attribute) == value);
}
```

<sup>Forgive my rusty C# skills in case there are syntax errors.</sup>