# How to implement a Selenium condition that waits for an attribute to change in C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I want to implement, using Selenium, a method that polls an HTML element for the value of one of its attributes, and waits for it to be different than a given value (in this case, the value that was there before). The below code is the method I implemented for this.

```
 private static string waitForAttributeToNotBe(By elementCondition, string attribute, string originalValue)
 {
     Func<IWebDriver, bool> testCondition = (x) => !(x.FindElement(elementCondition).GetAttribute(attribute).Equals(originalValue));

     //Wait is implemented above, as Wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

     Wait.Until(testCondition);

     return Driver.FindElement(elementCondition).GetAttribute(attribute);
 }
```

This has been working in my builds, but a specific build caused issues, namely, a StaleElementException.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : {"errorMessage":"Element does not exist in cache","request":{#ommitted#}}
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.GetAttribute(String attributeName)
  (...)
```

This exception was thrown evaluating the line that defines the Func.

I was under the assumption that explicitly defining the FindElement by the provided condition would avoid the issue of the element not being cached.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this? A more intelligent rephrasing?

Thank you,
JM

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example to wait for an attribute to be different:

```cs
string valueBefore = wait.Until(NotAttribute(By.cssSelector(...), "value", ""));
...
string valueAfter = wait.Until(NotAttribute(By.cssSelector(...), "value", valueBefore));
```

```cs
public static Func<IWebDriver, string> NotAttribute(By locator, string attribute, string notValue) {
    return (driver) => {
      try {
          var value = driver.FindElement(locator).GetAttribute(attribute);
          return value == notValue ? null : value;
      }
      catch (NoSuchElementException) {
          return null;
      }
      catch (StaleElementReferenceException) {
          return null;
      }
    };
}
```

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce my issue yet - it may have to do with site slowness coinciding with text execution. However, I will try your solution and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this.**

In Java-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); 
wait.until(ExpectedCondition.attributeContains(WebElement element,
                                               java.lang.String attribute,
                                               java.lang.String value));
```

**In C#-**

You can create your own custom expected condition

**Please refer this -** 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41048165/4193068

Comment: This is Java. C# doesn't have this expected condition.

Comment: This expected condition doesn't exist in the .NET options (see https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm). 

Still, looking at the source code it seems similar to my idea:

       `@Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return getAttributeOrCssValue(findElement(locator, driver), attribute)
            .map(seen -> seen.contains(value))
            .orElse(false);
      }`

Comment: Yes, that is the condition I implemented. Please see the definition of the Func<IWebDriver, bool> testCondition in the first snippet.

Comment: This issue generally occurs when DOM gets change and make the element inaccessible. Put that line in try and catch(StaleElementReferenceException e) and put this try catch in loop 2-3 so DOM could be ready.

Comment: If no exception raised in try block then use break to come out of the loop.